# Determining P(X = 1 | X + Y ≥ 0)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

Let $X$ denote a discrete random variable with PMF $P_X$ given by

$$ P_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0.2 &\text{ if x = −1,} \\
0.3 &\text{ if x = 0,} \\
0.5 &\text{ if x = 1,} \\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $Y$ denote a discrete random variable that is independent of $X$ and has PMF $P_Y$
given by
$$ P_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
0.3 &\text{ if y = −1,} \\
0.4 &\text{ if y = 0,} \\
0.3 &\text{ if y = 1,} \\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

How do I then calculate $P(X = 1 \mid X + Y \geq 0).$ if it was just $P(X = 1 \mid Y \geq 0)$ then I would be able to do it but I don't know how to do when it's like this: $P(X = 1 \mid X + Y \geq 0).$

So far i have only this:
$$
P(X = 1 | X + Y ≥ 0) = \frac{P(X = 1 \cap X + Y ≥ 0)}{P(X + Y ≥ 0)}
$$
But from here i can't calculate it like i normally would do and have tried many different things but can't find the right way to do it.

Comment: "So far I have..." What you have is wrong. First, the numerator should not be just the same thing as the left side, and the denominator is wrong.

Comment: These are discrete. You could enumerate all possible combinations and then examine among them, for instance?

Comment: I agree with @davidlowryduda. In fact there are only nine cases to look at, and using the independence assumption you can find the probability of each case. Then you can just find prob of event X=1 and divide by prob of event [X=1 and X+Y >= 0],

Comment: I don't understand what is the numerator and denominator then supposed to be?

Comment: As for the possible combinations i have these: $$X = -1, Y = 1: (X + Y = -1 + 1 = 0) \\
X = 0, Y = -1: (X + Y = 0 - 1 = -1) \\
X = 0, Y = 0: (X + Y = 0 + 0 = 0) \\
X = 1, Y = -1: (X + Y = 1 - 1 = 0) \\
X = 1, Y = 0: (X + Y = 1 + 0 = 1) \\
X = 1, Y = 1: (X + Y = 1 + 1 = 2) $$ Where only three combinations give me that $X = 1$ and also these three combinations $(1, -1)$, $(1, 0)$, $(1, 1)$ give me that $X + Y \geq 0$

Comment: Nvm i just noticed why the numerator is wrong. It's supposed to be (and) not (|). I just copied the left side and pasted it in and forget to change it. But i don't get why the denominator is wrong.

Comment: Nvm again i just noticed why the denominator is wrong and will correct it.

Comment: Okay i'm able to solve it if i include $X = 0, Y = -1: (X + Y = 0 - 1 = -1)$ in my calculations, but i can't see why it should be included considering it isn't greater than equal 0. Without it i get $\frac{0.5}{0.59} = 0.847$ and with it i get the correct result $\frac{0.5}{0.77} = 0.649$. But i can't make it make sense.

Comment: @Mohammed There are **9** ($\textrm{nine}$) possible combinations as already has written in one of the previous comments.

Comment: I know but only 6 of them are valid and i have managed to solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

From the conditional probability we have the following:
$$
P(X = 1 | X + Y ≥ 0) = \frac{P(X = 1 \cap X + Y ≥ 0)}{P(X + Y ≥ 0)}
$$

We now calculate $P(X = 1 \cap X + Y ≥ 0)$
\begin{align}
P(X = 1 \cap X + Y ≥ 0) &= P(X = 1, Y = -1) + P(X = 1, Y = 0) + P(X = 1, Y = 1) \\
&= (0.5 \cdot 0.3) + (0.5 \cdot 0.4) + (0.5 \cdot 0.3) \\
&= 0.5
\end{align}

Last but not least we now calculate $P(X + Y ≥ 0)$
\begin{align}
P(X + Y ≥ 0) &= P(X = -1, Y = 1) + P(X = 0, Y = 0) + P(X = 1, Y = -1) + P(X = 1, Y = 0) + P(X = 0, Y = 1) + P(X = 1, Y = 1) \\
&= (0.2 \cdot 0.3) + (0.3 \cdot 0.4) + (0.5 \cdot 0.3) + (0.5 \cdot 0.4) + (0.3 \cdot 0.3) + (0.5 \cdot 0.3) \\
&= 0.77
\end{align}

Therefore we now get:
\begin{align}
P(X = 1 | X + Y ≥ 0) &= \frac{P(X = 1 \cap X + Y ≥ 0)}{P(X + Y ≥ 0)} \\
&= \frac{0.50}{0.77} \\
&\approx 0.649
\end{align}